# Is there a way to run a C++ executable that uses SDL2 and SDL2 image without having the dll files in the repository?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I compiled the code in VS Code using the Makefile from LazyFoo website, made some changes to it (didn't touch the flags of course), as you can see below:

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = *.cpp

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = output

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

The code seems to get compiled (I get no compilation errors when I compile, like a "No such file or directory" error) but when I run my executable, I get this

[Error code when running exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FavU6.png)

Now I could add the dll files into the directory where this C++ code is but that clutters it up. I want to do it such that the exe file or something else knows where the dll files are on my PC, which is conveniently not in my workspace directory.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Static_linking

Comment: You can statically link SDL2 (meaning you don't need the .dlls). The SDL wiki has advice on how to do that here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Static_linking

Comment: Got it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so think people (including me) did not at first understand the question. My main concern was that I could not run an .exe file that my code made after compilation. I had already linked to the relevant directory where I stored all my headers and .lib  and .dll files. I couldn't **run** the .exe file without having the .dll files in my work directory (for example, if my .cpp and .hpp files were in folder A, then my .dll files needed to be in A to run the .exe file).

The workaround was that I added the .dll files into the Windows folder. I read it somewhere on the Internet (don't remember where) that Windows looks for such files to run executables inside the Windows folder, and I guess they were right.